# WIFSTOPPED is not working properly

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am trying to implement the `fg` command in my mini shell.
The problem is as follows:

- A process(gedit) is started in foreground.
- I stop with <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd> and check exit my wait loop by checking the return value of `WIFSTOPPED(status)`:

```c
while(1){
    pid_t pid_check = waitpid(pid,&signal,WNOHANG|WUNTRACED);
    if(pid_check == pid){
        if(WIFSTOPPED(signal)){
            tempid = pid_check;
            break;
        }
        else if(WIFEXITED(signal))
            break;
        else if(WIFSIGNALED(signal))
            break;
    }
    …
}
```

I want this to resume when fg command is given:

```
kill(tempid,SIGCONT);
while(1){
    pid_t pid_check = waitpid(pid,&signal,WNOHANG|WUNTRACED);
    if(pid_check == pid){
        if(WIFSTOPPED(signal)){
            tempid = pid_check;
            printf("Here");
            break;
        }
        else if(WIFEXITED(signal))
            break;
        else if(WIFSIGNALED(signal))
            break;
    }
}
```

But WIFSTOPPED keeps returning non zero so waitpid is breaking and process goes in background. I tried to search online but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: How do you declare `signal`?  It is often a function name from `<signal.h>`.  While it isn't obligatory to include `<signal.h>` when you're waiting, you have used `SIGCONT` which suggests you have included the signal header.  Does the code compile cleanly with no warnings, even when you use stringent warnings (`-Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow`)?

Comment: Yes the code compiles without any warnings

Comment: So how do you declare the variable `signal`?  I assume it must be `int signal;` — and you are not compiling with `-Wshadow`.  What that does is hides the function `signal` in the function (block) where you declare the variable.  That isn't formally wrong; it is a little unorthodox.  The value is really an exit status — it may encode a signal, or it may encode an actual exit status.  I'd certainly not use `signal` for the task.

Comment: Note that when printing diagnostic messages, it is crucial that the output ends with a newline (unless you've set `stdout` to unbuffered with `setvbuf()`).  So, use `printf("Here\n");` to determine where you are (or, better, something like `printf("Here: %d\n", __LINE__);` if you have more than one such statement).

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you're sending the continuation signal to `tempid`, then monitoring `pid`.

Check to make sure that these are set to the same PID, although it would probably be safer and more readable to just use:

```
kill(pid,SIGCONT);
```

before entering the monitoring loop.

You might also want to consider renaming your `signal` variable to avoid possible clashes with the `signal()` function.

Comment: Oh! I'm launching tempid and checking pid. I changed pid to tempid in waitpid(). That worked. Thanks